# CSV - How to bind the whole description as one record

Tags: csv

I need to transfer data (product details) **from one online store to another**.

I have exported data from **source store in .CSV** format. Now I want to create **target store compatible .CSV** to import to the target store.

There are field like: **"ProductCode, ProductName, ProductDescription"** and so on.

So in **ProductDescription** column if there is comma(,) present in ProductDescription so it goes to the next column from the comma(,).

How can I bind the whole description as one record for that particular product?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put double quotes (i.e. "") around the description.

Comment: then I'd open it up in an editor that supports macros, and add the quotes.  Something Notepad++(http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or SublimeText(http://www.sublimetext.com/)